# WebView with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences

I store my SharedPreference, but I don't know how to use it in a webview. 
In fact, I want to address that, depending on stored in the webview, it makes a request of http://myurlsharedpreference.com/mypage kind. So I want http: // myurlsharedpreference be added to / mypage and that everything displays a webview, it is possible and if so how are my variables to store:

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
CheckBox checkBox;
EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadSavedPreferences();
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
    if (checkBoxValue) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    editText.setText(name);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
        savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    finish();
}
```

}

Seccond Activity ( where i want when a button is clicked )

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    ImageButton imageButton2;
    ImageButton imageButton3;
    ImageButton imageButton4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnButton2();
        addListenerOnButton3();
        addListenerOnButton4();
    } 
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,
                "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton2() {

        imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {

               Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,
                "ImageButton2 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


        });

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton3() {

        imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg2) {

               Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,
                "ImageButton3 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton4() {

        imageButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

        imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg3) {

              /* Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,
                "ImageButton4 is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 */
                WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                String UsersURL = [taken from shared preferences];
                String UsersURL = UsersURL+"/mypage";
                myWebView.loadUrl(UsersURL);
            }


        });

    }
```

Comment: Wait, if I understand correctly: You want to load url from SharedPreferences and to the end of url add: /mypage ?
Then apply this URL to WebView?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
String UsersURL = [taken from shared preferences];
String UsersURL = UsersURL+"/mypage";
myWebView.loadUrl(UsersURL);
```

Edit:

In your first activity: 
You store your data in SharedPreferences, then you open new Activity which is called SecondActivity (for example).
Say you stored a String called: MyData with value of "Hello"

If you wish to retrieve values in SecondActivity from FirstActivity where you stored them in SharedPreferences:

You need to call SharedPreferences like this for example:

```
public String GetData(String dataname, String defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString(dataname, defaultValue);
    return name;
    }

Now within your second activity you call:
```

GetData("MyData", "No Value Set");

that will return string of data you stored before.

Comment: I have try, but in this activity the sharedpreference is not call ... 
My Code is in secondActivity so I have edited my first post

Comment: Wait, what stops you from getting sharedpreferences in 2nd activity?

Comment: I do not understand, I have to say again sharedpreference? When I test your code, it gives me a lot of errors suddenly I imagine there must miss enormously things

Comment: It's hard for me to understand, can you edit my code for example please, I would understand better

Comment: Did you retrieve shared preference variable in second activity?

Comment: No I haven't retrieve , I don't know why